# Error buy item InApp Billing Android

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

At the time I was going to buy an item InApp Billing had a errors and the application was closed, therefore the item was NOT consumed and I get this error:

Error: Unable to buy item (response: 7:Item Already Owned)

How to free an item that has not been consumed in case the app closes for some error?

Answer (score 0):

Consume it once again.

In general, billing transactions and consumptions should be atomic (tolerant to errors), or you may lose money/users.